# Personnal WP 8.1 DSK cannot implement in new project using NuGetPackage

Tags: mvvm, sdk, windows-phone-8.1, nuget-package

I'am actually working on a WindowsPhone 8.1 SDK project, that contains several Xaml view, that should be displayed from the host application. I am using MVVM Light and Portable Class Libraries to create the SDK.
My solution contains 3 projects dedicated to the SDK and 1 project as Sample (to test the SDK while developping) as following :

- Sdk.Models (Portable)
- Sdk.ViewModels (Portable)
- Sdk.WindowsPhone (Windows Phone 8.1) <--Contains view to display

---

- Sample.WindowsPhone (Windows Phone 8.1) <-- this one is for testing :)

Everything works great in the sample project, because it has references to three projects presented below.
I have finished a stable version of the SDK, so I wanted to test it in different WP8.1 project, by generating a NuGetPackage of the SDK.

So I use the [NuGet Package Explorer Tool](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases), that allows me to create then Package, including, my SDK DLLs, and all dependencies of others Packages.

However a problem appears when I'm trying to use my SDK, by including it to a new WP8.1 project via NuGet Manager of the solution. I can easily call different methodes of the SDK, but when I try to display one of the views that contains the SDK, the following Exception is thrown on the `this.InitializeComponent()` of the targeted view :

> An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException'
> occurred in Sdk.DLL but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: XAML parsing failed.

Does any one had the same problem ? Or something alike ?

Comment: Generally when this error is show, there is a mismatch between the namespaces given in the XAML and the code behing of the Page ( view ). Other than that it's difficult to assess the problem without some code.

Comment: Hello Depechie, I've just checked name spaces between my view and its associated Code Behind. It seems beeing correct.

Comment: Like I said, bit diffucult to verify without some example code :/

Comment: Sorry I was editing my comment ;) Here is the namespace of the code behind : `namespace MySdkProjectName.Sdk.WindowsPhone.View.Pages` and the same value is specified in the View Xaml : `xmlns:local="using:MySdkProjectName.Sdk.WindowsPhone.Views.Pages"`. Is there some special piece of code, I should show you ? Some says that I have to include "win81" library to my NuGet package, but I don't know how to do it using the NuGet Package Explorer Tool :/

Comment: Check the class name in the XAML file, what does it say there?

Comment: Exactly the same as for local with the class name at the end : `x:Class="MySdkProjectName.Sdk.WindowsPhone.View.Pages.InformationPage"`

Comment: Hmm sorry I'm out of options then... other than that if I look at my view the local tag should be ( in your example ) using:MySdkProjectName.Sdk.WindowsPhone ( without the views.pages )

Comment: Here is the entire Page container `<Page
    x:Class="MySdkProjectName.Sdk.WindowsPhone.Views.Pages.InformationPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MySdkProjectName.Sdk.WindowsPhone.Views.Pages"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    DataContext="{Binding Informations, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    >`

Comment: Depechie, I've tryed to remove "views.pages" from the local tag, but that does not changing anything... May be some one else will give some advice !  Anyway thank you for your suggestions, I have appreciated :)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I didn't add it to 'answer' because of the possibility it was not working at all ;) - I hope someone can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly find a solution to my problem !

I had to add all .xbf files of views that implement the SDK, and also of ResourceDictionnaries, itno the lib folder using NuGetPackage Explorer Tool.
Additionnaly I had to add .pri and .xr.xml files before generating a new package.

I hope this information will help other people ! :)